# Loop must iterate over a collection type: Map&lt;String,reports.DetailColumn&gt;

Tags: apex

```
Id reportId = '00O28000004oRjdEAE';
Reports.ReportDescribeResult reportDescription = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
Reports.ReportExtendedMetadata rEm = reportDescription.getReportExtendedMetadata();
Reports.ReportMetadata rm = reportDescription.getReportMetadata();
//List<String> lstDC=  rm.getDetailColumns();
System.debug(rEm.getDetailColumnInfo());    

for(Reports.DetailColumn dc : rEm.getDetailColumnInfo())
{
    System.debug(dc);   

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to say? What's your exact question? Just pasting your code won't help identifying the issue. Please elaborate your question by adding more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rEm.getDetailColumnInfo()` returns a map of type `Map<String,Reports.DetailColumn>` but you are iterating it as a list, thats why the error is coming.

Change your iteration like this :

```
for(Reports.DetailColumn dc : rEm.getDetailColumnInfo().values())
{
    System.debug(dc);   

}
```

or

```
for(String  tempStr : rEm.getDetailColumnInfo().keySet())
    {
      Reports.DetailColumn dc = rEm.getDetailColumnInfo().get(tempStr);

    }
```